# Dar valor TRUE al primer registro

Tags: sql

Quiero ordenar una tabla por 2 campos:

```
Producto-Precio
1-100
2-25
2-27
1-23
3-45
```

Hago un select order by por Producto y precio pero ahora lo que quiero es añadir un campo a mayores y que quede la tabla así:
Producto-Precio-Result

```
1-23-TRUE
1-100-FALSE
2-25-TRUE
2-27-FALSE
3-45-TRUE
```

Me podéis ayudar a definir cómo sería el proceso? Gracias!

Comment: Creo que tendrias que hacerlo ya con el lenguaje de programación que estes utilizando.

Comment: es un poco confuso tu pregunta

Comment: He puesto la tabla inicial y la tabla final. El lenguaje sería Sql, que es lo que no se entiende?

Comment: ¿Cual es la condición para que sea `TRUE` o `FALSE` un registro?

Comment: Que sea la primera por precio de cada producto

Comment: ¿Qué manejador de base de datos estás utilizando?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En caso de ser SQL-Server la otra forma, sin sub-selects, podría ser:

```
select
  a.producto,
  a.precio,
  case row_number() over (partition by a.producto order by a.precio)
      when 1 then 'true'
      else 'false'
  end
  from MiTabla a
  order by a.producto,
           a.precio
```

Comment: Basado en sus preguntas pasadas, sospecho que la base de datos es PostgreSQL. (Anna: siempre es importante especificar cual base de datos usas) Si es el caso, tu respuesta funcionará bien también. Solo 2 detalles: 1) aun necesitas un `ORDER BY` al final de la consulta para ordenar los resultados, 2) No hay necesidad de incluir `a.producto` en el `order by` dentro del `row_number()`.

Comment: Buena aclaración con lo del ORDER BY final (editado). Con respecto al del row_number() al menos en SQL Server es obligatorio. Saludos..

Comment: No digo que no sea obligatorio. Solo digo que el `order by` en el `row_number()` puede limitarse a `order by a.precio`. Incluir `a.producto` allí no hace nada porque el orden se aplica después de particionar los registros. Y como ya los particionas por producto, no existen valores diferentes de producto a la hora de plica el orden. Solo necesitas ordenar por precio en ese momento.

Comment: Entiendo, ahí lo modifiqué, gracias por el comentario.

Answer (score 2):

Si entendí bien, creo que estas buscando algo como esto:

```
select
  a.producto,
  a.precio,
  resultado = case when a.precio = (select top 1 precio from MiTabla where producto=a.producto order by precio asc) then 'true' else 'false' end
from MiTabla a
order by  a.producto, a.precio asc;
```

puedes probarlo aqui:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/6e460/3